# How to decide what layers to use for content and style loss in style transfer?

Tags: deep-learning, style-transfer

When you choose a pretrained network for style transfer to determine style and content loss you need to decide which layers best represent the perceived style and content and use them to make said losses. How does one go about choosing such layers?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the way a fully convolutional NN works is that the shallow CNN layers are capturing more simple features such as lines and squares, and the deeper ones are combining them to capture more complex ones(faces, shoes, etc). So for feature caption, you may want to use a deeper layer. When it comes to style, as you might know, it usually uses a combination of different layers.

My two cents.

Comment: At the time of writing I was wondering if there was a more fundamental reason one layer would be chosen over another. I realize now it’s just a heuristic. Could maybe be an interesting area of research. Thank you for the answer.